# Hololens emulator APPX install error 0x80073cfd

Tags: windows, hololens, appx

I am trying to install an UWP (APPX) application on a Hololens emulator but I get this error:

> Failure reason: Failed to start deployment. Failure text: A
>   Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied.  (0x80073cfd)

The APPX has been converted by using Desktop App Converter. I can successfully install it on my PC running Windows 10. I don't know what that error means and how can I debug it. Documentation sucks big time!

I have also tried the x64 arch and I get this (which makes sense...)

> Failure reason: Failed to start deployment. Failure text: The
>   deployment operation failed because the package targets the wrong
>   processor architecture.  (0x80073d10)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Desktop App Converter does not actually convert an application into a UWP App, it wraps the .net 4.6.1+ application in a UWP app so that it can be distributed in the store and run as a UWP app.  The platform you are deploying the App to must be capable of running a .net 4.6.1+ application for this to work.  Currently the HoloLens is not capable of running these applications.

Comment: Thanks Cameron! How do I find out what is Hololens capable of running? And how can I make my windows desktop application run on Hololens? ...because at the end this is what I need to do.Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of ways of creating HoloLens applications, the Microsoft endorsed ways are: By creating a UWP application (2d), a Direct 3d application, a Unity 3d application, or HoloJS (3d webgl).  In addition there are some other 3rd party options like UrhoSharp from Xamarin. 

 If you are wanting to convert your 2d application to work on HoloLens, the easiest path is to convert it into a UWP application.  From there it should be easy to get running on a HoloLens

Comment: damn! I thought that Windows Desktop App Converter does that...it would have been too good to be true. The major problem is that I want to convert this open source app (https://github.com/gpac/gpac - which is quite complex) and put it on Hololens but I don't know what steps should I follow.

Comment: That project is complex and porting it to UWP would be very time consuming.  I don't have any suggestions for you besides forking the repo and assembling a team that wants to work on it.

Comment: thank you Cameron! I will investigate more in the hope that porting the project to UWP will not require so many resources..

Comment: @Traian you converted it?,

Comment: @NihalChandwani, no. It is not possible to convert an application to UWP just like that. You have to build the UWP app from scratch basically. In the best case scenario you can take the code from the old application and reuse it in the new UWP app, however a simple copy/paste will not do it for sure :)